# JavaFX CheckBoxTableCell catch ClickEvent

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Using the `CheckBoxTableCell` in a `TableView` I wan't to perform some code when the user clicks the checkbox. 
This code needs to be performed before the CheckBox get's checked and before the associated property is changed.

Since `CheckBoxTableCell` does not trigger `startEdit()`, `commitEdit()` and so on I need another point where I can put my code.

`updateItem()` would be too late, since the value has already been changed there.

Does anybody know any other place where I can insert my code? Or am I better of just writing my own CheckBoxTableCell?

For those who want to think further: When the user checks the checkBox I want to run a code that checks if his decision may cause him problems later on. When the property changes I have a changeListener that uploads the new value to a database. If there may be any problems (my code returns true) then there should be the obligatory error message: "Do you really want to do this...blabla" and only if he confirms the check box should be actually checked, the value changed and uploaded to the database.

This is how I set up my `CheckBoxTableCell`:

```
    //init cell factories
    Callback<TableColumn<PublicMovie, Boolean>, TableCell<PublicMovie, Boolean>> checkBoxCellFactory
            = (TableColumn<PublicMovie, Boolean> p) -> new CheckBoxTableCell<>();
    //Assign Column
    allMoviesCheckBoxColumn = (TableColumn<PublicMovie, Boolean>) allMoviesTableView.getColumns().get(0);
    //Set CellValueFactory
    allMoviesCheckBoxColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getSomeBooleanProperty();
```

`someBooleanProperty` has a listener. When changed to true, the `statusProperty` changes to `1`.

This code snippet is in the constructor of the `TableView`s underlying class. Whenever the user clicks the CheckBox, it is executed.

```
    this.status.addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
        DataHandler.fireOnChangedEvent(PublicMovieChangeListener.STATUS_CHANGED, getMovie(), newValue, oldValue);
    });
```

`DataHandler` holds a list of `Listeners` (so far only one). The following code is executed when the `onChange` event is called by the `DataHandler`:

```
@Override
public void onChange(int changeID, PublicMovie changedPublicMovie, Object newValue, Object oldValue) {
    switch (changeID) {
        case STATUS_CHANGED:
            boolean mayUpdate = check(); 
            //check is a placeholder for the code that checks for problems.
            //It will return false if there might be a problem.

            if(!mayUpdate){
                    mayUpdate = ErrorDialogs.getConfirmationDialog("Überfüllung!", header, content);
            }
            if (mayUpdate) {
                updateMovie(changedPublicMovie);
            } else {
                changedPublicMovie.getStatusProperty().set((int) oldValue);
                refreshAllMoviesTable();
            }
            break;
        case THREE_DIM_CHANGED:
            updateMovie(changedPublicMovie);
            break;
        case CHILDREN_CHANGED:
            updateMovie(changedPublicMovie);
            break;
    }
```

What you can see here is my attempt to reverse the changed Property... but the checkbox remains checked. Thus I'm looking for a way to perform the checking prior to changing the Property.

Comment: Please post some code. The `CheckBoxTableCell` should be linked to a `BooleanProperty` in the table's model. You can register listeners with that property.

Comment: What code do you need? I used all the standart code to implement a `CheckBoxTableCell`... I have a listener there (the one that then starts the upload to the database). I posted the code that I use there in a sec...

Comment: OK, if I understand correctly you are wanting to potentially veto the change? I think in that case you need to implement your own cell.

Comment: Yeah that's what I want... Sad to hear but I see something to start with down there.... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the documentation of [`CheckBoxTableCell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.html):

> If you want to be notified of changes, it is recommended to directly
>   observe the boolean properties that are manipulated by the `CheckBox`.

I don't say that it is impossible with `CheckBoxTableCell`, but most probably it is not so straightforward.

This kind of "pre-select" events can be managed in most of the cases with `EventFilter`s.

Therefore you could try to use a normal `TableColumn` with the appropriate `cellFactory` that utilizes these `EventFilter`s.

**My example**

*The used `cellFactory`:*

```
tableCol.setCellFactory(p -> {
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
    TableCell<Person, Boolean> tableCell = new TableCell<Person, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {

            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty || item == null) 
                setGraphic(null);
            else {
                setGraphic(checkBox);
                checkBox.setSelected(item);
            }
        }
    };

    checkBox.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> 
        validate(checkBox, (Person) cell.getTableRow().getItem(), event));

    checkBox.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
        if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE)
            validate(checkBox, (Person) cell.getTableRow().getItem(), event);
    });

    tableCell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    tableCell.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

    return tableCell;
});
```

*and the used `validate` method*:

```
private void validate(CheckBox checkBox, Person item, Event event){
    // Validate here
    event.consume();

    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Confirmation Dialog");
    alert.setHeaderText("Look, a Confirmation Dialog");
    alert.setContentText("Are you ok with this?");

    // Set the checkbox if the user want to continue
    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
    if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK)
        checkBox.setSelected(!checkBox.isSelected());
}
```

**What is does:**

It renders a simple `CheckBox` and adds two `EventFilter`s to this `CheckBox`. The first one is executed on mouse press, the second one on keypress (here the `KeyCode.SPACE` is used). Both of them call the `validate` method. The `validate` method consumes the event (ensures that the selection state of the `CheckBox` is not modified), "validates" the input (no validation on my side) then shows a confirmation dialog. If the user agrees, the `selectedProperty` of the `CheckBox` is set.

Comment: That was the approach I was going to go if everything fails... Thanks for giving me something to start with!

Comment: I am not sure but I think in the upper example the checkbox will never change its selection as the event is consumed no matter what `validate` returns. If it should change, could you please explain why?

Comment: Hah, yes, you are true. It seems that the `alert.showAndWait()` consumes the event anyways (it worked as I expected so I haven't even noticed this). The second example works as expected (I like that one anyways better - maybe I will update the asnwer to only contain this one).

Comment: A little late to the party but thanks, this is exactly what I needed! One small improvement:

Instead of using both I Mouse and Key Event handler, I used:

checkBox.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> {
  //Code
}

I think this will cover both Mouse Clicks and Key Presses.

(Sorry can't format code in Comments)